# what is the use of 'jsx' property in tsconfig.json

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I had generated tsconfig.json with `tsc --init`,

and then I wrote react code in a .tsx file and got the error `Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided`

I stumbled upon this `jsx` setting of `tsconfig`

it has `jsx` in commented mode as 
`// "jsx": "preserve",   /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react', 'react-jsx'. */`

so what do those three options mean? namely `preserve`, `react-native` and `react`

Answer (score 44):

`jsx` property allows us to use .tsx files in the project

**So following are two steps of using React with Typescript**

> 1.Name your files with a .tsx extension
>
> 2.Enable the jsx option

TypeScript ships with three JSX modes: preserve, react, and react-native.

These modes only affect the emit stage - type checking is unaffected. 
**The `preserve` mode will keep the JSX as part of the output to be further consumed by another transform step (e.g. Babel).** Additionally, the output will have a .jsx file extension.
 **The `react` mode will emit React.createElement, does not need to go through a JSX transformation before use, and the output will have a .js file extension.** 
**The `react-native` mode is the equivalent of preserve in that it keeps all JSX, but the output will instead have a .js file extension.**
 **`react-jsx` (relevant for React 17) mode helps you to avoid the necessity of importing React in every file where jsx is used, i.e. it will emit**

React has introduced a new JSX transform with the release of React 17 which automatically transforms JSX without using React.createElement. This allows us to not import React, however, you'll need to import React to use Hooks and other exports that React provides
https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage

Comment: IMO as you are creating a React App, you should use the 'react' mode.

Comment: That's not 100% accurate, it does affect type checking. If you set 'preserve' it won't warn you about missing React import for instance.

Comment: is there a way to preserve,but create a js file instead of jsx

Comment: What about `"jsx": "react-jsx"`?

Comment: /* helps avoid react import in file */
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

Comment: As of this writing there's also react-native and react-jsxdev, handbook has a nice table which breaks it down : 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html